# Of a deck of 2000 cards, how many review sessions of 50 random cards must be made until 95% of cards are reviewed?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm working on reviewing my notes through 2000 flashcards, I figure that if I review 50 cards, twice a day for a month this would be sufficient to get almost all cards?

Is there some sort of equation to determine how many times I will need to have a review session?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: If this is asking for advice on actual study habits, it is not ideal to pick the cards randomly.  Try to seed the cards that you encountered which you got wrong or are uncomfortable with at a higher rate until you comfortably get them right.  I recommend using software like [anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) to facilitate this.

Comment: Simulation confirms that after $126$ sessions, you can be $99\%$ confident you have seen $95\%$ of the cards. [Here is the python code.](https://tio.run/##ZVHtaoQwEPyfp9g/5QwVGq9YuIKFvkfhCLqeAd1IEjmOq89u82GtR0NgYXZmMrsZb67T9LosrdEDGEmNL2oYtXFg5TD2yFiDLTijZJ8Rf2fgj0UkqHxxGY9Aqw2cQVFwuODGe@D68h0lyTdL1KMQgudQCp6cDLrJEPRIWZBw@KigOAmxxkDrMsqBpuEcI1lvXYj1OVnX0@ABsWVyu0ybZBcuKZ6rbb7YGY2i38nWPIn4snuYsYcQpY8Y5iyObyzp28Nn69CAmYgUXeD@x5/jIDaHRqfODNZNzc2vx1qlyQLKugOnBszhi1yHPpMOn@KboNvYsXDt0CCcyqcA1dI0HgpI3PVVWi8N9/5/a3w@cLYsPw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You certainly need a lot of study sessions. After $118$ sessions, the average number of cards seen is $1-(1950/2000)^{118}\approx 95\%$, but due to variance it will be sometimes above and sometimes below. Simulation confirms that $118$ sessions puts you below $95\%$ about half the time. To be safe, you need to up the number of sessions to $126$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be computed explicitly using a homogeneous Markov chain. The transition matrix from going of a collection of $i$ cards to a collection of $j$ cards is defined by

$$
p_{i,j}=\frac{\binom{N-i}{j-i}\binom{i}{n_0-j+i}}{\binom{N}{n_0}}
$$

where $N$ is the total number of cards and $n_0$ is the amount of cards that you view in a session (I'm assuming here that all cards seen in a session are different). Then for $N=2000$ and $n_0=50$ I get

[image]

By example, after $101$ study sessions the probability that the shown cards are above $1819$ ($\approx 91\%$ of all cards) is more than $95\%$. And the first time that the $5$-percentile is greater than the $95\%$ of total cards (i.e. greater than $1900$) happens in the $125$-th session.

The Julia code used to plot the above is this

```
using Distributions, SparseArrays, GLMakie

# This function defines our transition matrix:
function tm(N::Int, n0::Int)
    [pdf(Hypergeometric(N-l,l,n0),k-l) for l in 0:N, k in 0:N]
end

# This computes the 5-percentile of a probability vector
function percentile5(M::AbstractVector)
    s=0
    i=0
    while s <= 0.05
        i += 1
        s += M[i]
    end
    return i-1
end

# This function compute a matrix with three rows: means, 5-percentiles 
# and standard deviations. Each column represent a session.
function stats(N::Int, n0::Int, m::Int)    
    A = transpose(sparse(tm(N,n0)))
    sup = 0:N # The support of each distribution
    sup2 = sup .^2
    C = A[:,1]
    stats = zeros(3,m)
    for i in 1:m
        stats[1,i] = sum(C .* sup)
        stats[2,i] = percentile5(C)
        stats[3,i] = sqrt(sum(C .* sup2) - stats[1,i]^2)
        C = A * C
    end
    return stats
end

data = stats(2000,50,200)

fig = Figure()
ax1 = Axis(fig[1, 1],xlabel = "Number of sessions", ylabel="Shown cards")
ax2 = Axis(fig[2, 1],xlabel = "Number of sessions")
x = 1:200

lines!(ax1,x,data[1,:], color = :blue, label = "Average number of shown cards")
lines!(ax1,x,data[2,:], color = :red, label = "5-percentile of shown cards")
lines!(ax2,x,data[3,:], color = :green, label = "Standard deviation of shown cards")
axislegend(ax1, position = :rb)
axislegend(ax2, position = :rb)
fig
```

UPDATE: I updated the code with an insanely faster version.