# How many coin flips would it take to have a 90% chance of flipping 3 heads in a row?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

If you were to flip a fair coin independently over and over, hoping to get 3 heads in a row, how many coin flips would it take for you to have a 90+% chance of having succeeded?

The way I've been thinking about this problem is as a Markov Chain with states: 0, 1, 2, and 3 heads in a row, where 3 is the absorptive state.

[image: Markov chain diagram]

The transition matrix T is:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5&0&0\\0.5&0&0.5&0\\0.5&0&0&0.5\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

So roughly, what I'd like to be able to do is solve for n in the following equation  (let $k_1, k_2$, and $k_3$ be arbitrary constants):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}*T^n =\begin{bmatrix}k_1&k_2&k_3&0.9\end{bmatrix}$$

Through trial and error on the calculator, I can figure out that [1 0 0 0]$*T^{30}\approx$ [0.050 0.027 0.014 0.908].

However, I'd like to be able to do this in a systematic way that could be applied to other Markov Chains, but I'm not sure how. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome. Great first question!

Comment: you can't go further without simplifying the computations, so there is two ways: simplify the matrix product using a different basis or use a computer to do the calculations. For the second approach you can see [this example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4578878/of-a-deck-of-2000-cards-how-many-review-sessions-of-50-random-cards-must-be-mad/4579287#4579287) for explicit computations of the probabilities. A third approach, the "brute force" approach, is just computing it using a Montecarlo simulation

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez When I was writing the question, I was envisioning MCs with a maximum of around 10 states. All these responses have been great and I have a bunch of stuff to look into now. Even the fact that it depends on the size of the MC is very interesting!

Comment: OEIS: [A050231](http://oeis.org/A050231)

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing sounds pretty systematic to me. If $n$ is the number of states then it'll take you $O(n^3)$ time to do one matrix multiplication, so $O(\log(e)n^3)$ to compute a matrix power $T^e$. Thus binary searching over all powers up to $P$ to find the smallest power that works will cost $O(\log(P) \log(e) n^3)$ which is totally manageable for many Markov chains.

If you have some goals that are not fulfilled by this algorithm, you should explain what those goals are so you can get better answers. For example, if you need to answer this question for MCs with 100k+ states then you should specify that in the question or even ask a new question and specify there.

Comment: the point here is to avoid the matrix multiplication and computing iteratively $\mathbf{v}_n\mapsto \mathbf{v}_nT=:\mathbf{v}_{n+1}$ starting from $\mathbf{v}_0=(1,0,0,0)$, what is a lot faster than doing matrix multiplication

Comment: @Masacroso It just comes down to OP specifying that he wants to solve the problem for other MCs but not specifying what other problem he actually wants to solve. I could easily make up a bigger problem where my method is great and yours is bad (change probabilities so the answer turns out to be $10^{15}$ timesteps. I could also easily make up a bigger problem where your method is great and mine is bad ($10^5$ states but we usually finish in a few timesteps). For that reason, you could consider writing a separate answer with your method; I think they could both be helpful.

Comment: I was originally thinking of MCs with a maximum of around 10 states, but just the fact that "guess-and-check" is a viable option is surprising and interesting to me! Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach:

The problem can be attacked by recursion.

For $~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}, ~$
let $f~(N)~$ denote the number of sequences of $N$ coin flips that do not contain $~3~$ consecutive Heads.

The goal is to compute

$$\text{the smallest value of} ~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 3}}, ~\text{such that} ~f(N) < (0.1) \times 2^N. \tag1 $$

Let $~f(N,0)~$ denote the number of sequences of $N$ coin flips that do not contain $~3~$ consecutive Heads, where the last coin flip is a Tails.

Let $~f(N,1)~$ denote the number of sequences of $N$ coin flips that do not contain $~3~$ consecutive Heads, where the last two coin flips are Tails, Heads.

Let $~f(N,2)~$ denote the number of sequences of $N$ coin flips that do not contain $~3~$ consecutive Heads, where the last three coin flips are Tails, Heads, Heads.

Then:

- $f(N) = f(N,0) + f(N,1) + f(N,2).$
- $f(N+1,0) = f(N).$
- $f(N+1,1) = f(N,0) = f(N-1).$
- $F(N+1,2) = f(N,1) = f(N-2).$

This implies that for $~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 6}},~$ 
$f(N) = f(N-1) + f(N-2) + f(N-3).$

Then:

- $F(3,0) = 4, ~F(3,1) = 2, ~F(3,2) = 1 \implies F(3) = 7.$
- $F(4,0) = 7, ~F(4,1) = 4, ~F(4,2) = 2 \implies F(4) = 13.$
- $F(5,0) = 13, ~F(5,1) = 7, ~F(5,2) = 4 \implies F(5) = 24.$
- $F(6) = 44.$
- $F(7) = 81.$

For $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}},~$ let $~a_k~$ denote $~\dfrac{F(k-1)}{F(k)}.$

Then $~ \displaystyle a_4 = \frac{7}{13}, ~a_5 = \frac{13}{24}, ~a_6 = \frac{24}{44} \implies 
\frac{10}{19} < a_4, ~a_5, ~a_6 < \frac{10}{18}.$

For $~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 7}},~$ suppose that $~ \displaystyle \frac{10}{19} < a_{N-3}, ~a_{N-2}, ~a_{N-1} < \frac{10}{18}.$

This implies that

$$\left[\frac{10}{19}\right]^3 < a_{N-3} \times  a_{N-2} \times a_{N-1} < \left[\frac{10}{18}\right]^3.$$

Then

$$a_N = \frac{F(N-1)}{F(N)} = 
\frac{F(N-4) + F(N-3) + F(N-2)}{F(N-3) + F(N-2) + F(N-1)} $$

$$= 
\frac{F(N-3) + F(N-2) + F(N-1)}{F(N-3) + F(N-2) + F(N-1)} 
+
\frac{F(N-4) - F(N-1)}{F(N-3) + F(N-2) + F(N-1)}
$$

$$= 1 + \frac{F(N-4)}{F(N)} - \frac{F(N-1)}{F(N)} \implies $$

$$2a_N = 2 \times \frac{F(N-1)}{F(N)} = 1 + \frac{F(N-4)}{F(N)} \implies $$

$$2a_N = 1 + \left[ ~\left( ~a_{N_3} \times a_{N-2} \times a_{N-1} ~\right) \times a_N~\right] \implies $$

$$a_N \times \left[ ~2 - \left( ~a_{N_3} \times a_{N-2} \times a_{N-1} ~\right) ~\right] = 1 \implies $$

$$a_N = \frac{1}{2 - \left( ~a_{N_3} \times a_{N-2} \times a_{N-1} ~\right)} \implies $$

$$\frac{10}{19} < \frac{1}{2 - \left[ ~\left(\frac{10}{19}\right)^3 ~\right]} < a_n < 
\frac{1}{2 - \left[ ~\left(\frac{10}{18}\right)^3 ~\right]} < \frac{10}{18}.$$

Thus,

$$\forall ~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}}, ~\frac{10}{19} < a_N < \frac{10}{18}. $$

Further,

$$\forall ~N \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 4}}, ~f(N) = 
\frac{F(3)}{a_4 \times a_5 \times \cdots \times a_N} \implies $$

$$7 \times \left[ ~(1.8)^{N-3} ~\right] < F(N) < 7 \times \left[ ~(1.9)^{N-3} ~\right]. \tag2 $$

---

The result in (2) above may now be used to establish lower and upper bounds for the computation in (1) above.

$$7 \times [1.9]^{N-3} < 0.1 \times 2^N \implies F(N) < 0.1 \times 2^N.$$

Then,

$$N \geq 46 \implies N-3 \geq 43 \implies $$

$$\log\left[\frac{7}{.8}\right] < (N-3) \times  \log\left[\frac{2}{1.9}\right] \implies $$

$$\frac{7}{.8} < \left[\frac{2}{1.9}\right]^{N-3} \implies $$

$$7 \times (1.9)^{N-3} < 0.8 \times 2^{N-3} = 0.1 \times 2^N.$$

So, $~46~$ is an upper bound for $N$.

---

$$7 \times [1.8]^{N-4} > 0.1 \times 2^{N-1} \implies F(N-1) > 0.1 \times 2^{N-1}.$$

Then,

$$N \leq 24 \implies N-4 \leq 20 \implies $$

$$\log\left[\frac{7}{.8}\right] > (N-4) \times  \log\left[\frac{2}{1.8}\right] \implies $$

$$\frac{7}{.8} > \left[\frac{2}{1.8}\right]^{N-4} \implies $$

$$7 \times (1.8)^{N-4} > 0.8 \times 2^{N-4} = 0.1 \times 2^{N-1}.$$

So, $~24~$ is a lower bound for $N$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C_n=$ number of sequences of $n$ tosses with at least $3$ consecutive heads.

We have $C_0=C_1=C_2=0$, and $C_3=1$.

For $n\ge4$, we have $C_n=2C_{n-1}+2^{n-4}-C_{n-4}$.

Explanation:
$2C_{n-1}=$ number of sequences of $n$ tosses with $3$ consecutive heads before last toss (last toss is either heads or tails).
$2^{n-4}-C_{n-4}=$ number of sequences of $n$ tosses with $3$ consecutive heads for the first time with the last toss (last $4$ results are $THHH$, and before that there were no $3$ consecutive heads).

We require $\dfrac{C_n}{2^n}\ge0.9$. Using excel, we find that $n_{\text{min}}=30$.

Comment: Would this generalize (for x heads in a row) to Cₙ = 2Cₙ₋₁ + 2^(n-(x+1)) - Cₙ₋₍ₓ₊₁₎?

Comment: @JoeLoe Yes, that's right, for $n\ge x+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find matrixes $P$ and $D$ such that $T=PDP^{-1}$, then by induction $T^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ (the base case $n=1$ is trivial, then if we have the induction hypothesis $T^{n-1}=PD^{n-1}P^{-1}$, it follows that $T^n = T(T^{n-1})=PDP^{-1}PD^{n-1}P^{-1}$, and that easily simplifies to $PD^nP^{-1}$). If $D$ is diagonal, i.e. all non-diagonal entries are zero, and diagonal entries are $\lambda_i$, then $D^n$ is easily calculated as having diagonal entries $\lambda_i^n$. $T$ and $D$ are similar, so they have the same eigenvalue spectrum, so the $\lambda_i$ are simply the eigenvalues of $T$. $P$ is given by the eigenvectors that correspond to each eigenvalue.

I found a [calculator](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/linear-algebra/diagonalize-matrix-calculator/?i=%5B%5B.5%2C.5%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B.5%2C0%2C.5%2C0%5D%2C%5B.5%2C0%2C0%2C.5%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D) for diagonalizing matrices. Not all Markov chains can be diagonalized, so in some cases you have to use the [Jordan Canonical Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

In practice, though, it's often simpler to just calculate directly. You can calculate $T^{2^k}$ for integers $k$ until you get a value that's too large (just square the previous matrix to get the next one, i.e. $T^{2^{k+1}}=(T^{2^k})^2$), then do a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem with the Binomial distribution. For $n \ge k$ runs you have $n-k+1$ possible sequences of length $k$, where for your question $k=3$. Then the probability of getting at least one run of $k$ heads in a row is \begin{equation} P= 1- \binom{n-k+1}{0}\left(\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^0 \left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)^{n-k+1} \end{equation}
Setting $k=3$ and $P=0.9$ and solving for $n$,we get
\begin{equation} n = \frac{\log(0.1)}{\log(\frac{7}{8})}+2 \approx 19.2 \end{equation}
Meaning for each run with 20 flips or greater, your probability of getting at least one sequence of 3 heads is greater than 90%.

Comment: Great first answer! Hope to see your future input :)

Comment: Any idea why your conclusion of 20 flips disagrees with the 30 flips that I found? Or are they separate?